# optional value error found nil swift 3

Tags: class, swift3, xcode8

I was trying to assign a value to a var but I get this error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

the code:

```
vehicle.chassis = Chasis.text
```

but the variable is not an optional, I declare the variable this way:

```
var vehicle: Vehicle!
```

how can I fix this problem?

[check the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qvrh8.png)

Comment: It's an Optional, specifically an "implicitly unwrapped Optional".

Comment: But that's why I am assigning a value, to be sure not to be nil any more :-(

Comment: I already check that post

Comment: do you know how is the appropriate way to assign values in this case?

Comment: Ok, I've posted an answer for what I think is your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set a *property* to an instance that doesn't exist, because the implicitly unwrapped Optional `vehicle` is nil.

You can't set `vehicle.chassis` if `vehicle` is nil.

Before accessing `.chassis` you have to populate `vehicle` somewhere with an instance of `Vehicle`, for example in an init, or in viewDidLoad, etc:

```
vehicle = Vehicle()
```

and *then* you can access the `.chassis` property:

```
vehicle.chassis = Chasis.text
```

Answer (score 0):

To clarify what some of the above commenters have already mentioned, you're declaring your property as an Implicitly Unwrapped Optional (IUO herein).  Only optionals in Swift can be nil, but optionals must be unwrapped, IUO's don't need to be unwrapped, but might crash.  IUO's exist for 2 reasons.

1. To provide an unsafe/more raw access to your property to achieve ingrained Objective-C design patterns more quickly.  That is, directly act on "pointers" that may or may not be nil and crash when it is.
2. To provide a non-optional interface to properties that you cannot guarantee will be initialized by the time your class/struct init finishes, but you can guarantee will be initialized by the time you use it.  Useful for something the compiler can't verify but you as a programmer can.

That being said, I can only think of 2 sane proper ways to use IUO's in a Swifty manner, 1 is for IBOutlets, these aren't compiled by the swift compiler, don't exist after init(), but are guaranteed to be fulfilled by the time you use it (if your nib isn't corrupt), perfect use case for IUO's.
Another, while less imperative since it can be designed around, is Database models where you want lazy reads (which in itself is a bit of a pain to implement anyway)